# Ruby on rails dynamically populate sub categoies based on category form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

In short in a nested form add category to a product and based on that category populate subcategory for user to choose from.

I am using nested form gem in which I am specifying a category to a product.Now I need to specify a sub category to the product in the same form based on the category that I select. How to populate the subcategories dynamically.
Some gem to make life simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand 100%, but I had sort of the same problem.

first, nested forms are fine when things are simple, but it gets really complicated if not impossible to maintain when things go rough.

second, I suggest doing it in js since what you basically need is (correct me here) 2 select inputs, one for category and one for subcategory

those 2 selects are bind together, and it is best to do that with js, specifically with http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

since you are using form_for you would need to create your own s and add appropriate classes for each since `f.select` doesn't help you with that

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am using nested form gem in which I am specifying a category to a product.Now I need to specify a sub category to the product in the same form based on the category that I select. How to populate the subcategories dynamically.

Comment: you can't populate it dynamically without ajax. And since you want to use a nested form, you have to use UJS

Comment: I ended up following Railscasts PRO #88 Dynamic Select Menus (revised). Its working now. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.